# nsis: How do I create a start menu shortcut to open a folder?

Tags: nsis

My NSIS installer creates Start Menu links to run and uninstall my application.

**Using NSIS, how do I create StartMenu shortcut to open a folder in Windows Explorer?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the same as any other shortcut

```
CreateShortcut "$smprograms\my app\my shortcut.lnk" "c:\path\to\folder"
```

this is explorer 99% of the time, and its really what you want, but if you want to force explorer

```
CreateShortcut "$smprograms\my app\my shortcut.lnk" "$windir\explorer.exe" '/e,"c:\path\to\folder"'
```

but that shortcut will have the wrong icon etc

Comment: Thanks.  It turns out I had a typo in my path.